# C++ Perfect Forwarding

Tags: c++

1)

```
template<typename T, typename Arg> 
  shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg arg)
  { 
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg));
  }
```

2)

```
template<typename T, typename Arg> 
  shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg& arg)
  { 
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg));
  }
```

3)

```
template<typename T, typename Arg> 
  shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg const & arg)
  { 
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg));
  }
```

*)Why is number 3 is preferred than number 1 and number 2?

*)if factory(41) is called, why is called on rvalue?

*)# define BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(type) type&&.   what's && in this case?

Comment: You might want to look up *rvalue references*.  They're the "correct" way to do this and were introduced into the language partly for this purpose.  It also explains the `type&&` notation.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, approach #3 is *not* better than 1 and 2. It all depends on `T`'s constructor(s).

A somewhat standard way to do this is using *rvalue* references, which are the `&&` you mention.

So, a better factory would be something like this: (which is what *perfect forwarding* actually is)

```
template<typename T, typename Arg> 
std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg && arg)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T (std::forward<Arg>(arg)));
}
```

Due to *reference collapsing* rules of C++, this function can take (and forward) both rvalue refences and lvalue references, i.e., if you pass it an rvalue, it will forward that rvalue faithfully to `T`'s constructor, and if you give it an lvalue, the two kinds of reference (`Something & && arg`) will collapse and the lvalue reference will be forwarded to the underlying constructor.

I think I covered your questions here, but to answer explicitly,

- #3 is *not* the preferred method here. Even before C++11, you probably wanted both `const&` and `&` overloads of the `factory` function. The `const&` version is nicer and it will actually accept temporary values, but if your underlying `T` type has a constructor that accepts a non-const ref, then you would get a compile error because a `const&` is not implicitly casted to a `&`.
- Because you can't take the address of the literal `41` (this is not 100% technically correct, but I think it's OK to think of lvalues and rvalues this way.)
- It signifies an `rvalue reference`. You need to read about that; an explanation will not fit here, and there are already several great ones just a Google search away!

---

**UPDATE**: As mentioned tangentially in the comments, using `make_shared` can be better than constructing a `shared_ptr` with a just-`new`ed pointer. `make_shared` might achieve better efficiency by allocating the control block (which includes the reference count) along with the object itself, which would provide better cache locality when accessing the reference counter and the object, and also may save one memory allocation. Even if the implementation has none of the optimizations, it won't be any worse than the above version. So use `std::make_shared` whenever possible! And this would be how you do it here:

```
template<typename T, typename Arg> 
std::shared_ptr<T> factory (Arg && arg)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

Comment: @SoapBox: No, the type is indeed needed for the call to `forward`. Check out here: http://ideone.com/2v6Ytz

Comment: It's `std::forward<Arg>(arg)`, you don't need to form a reference for its argument.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oh, right! Because it removes the reference in the type anyways, right?

Comment: @yzt because it adds an rvalue reference, you're just doing unnecessary legwork. The `remove_reference` business is just to defeat deduction.

Comment: You should note that a slight improvement to #1, namely `return shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::move(arg)));`, is nearly as efficient as your `template` version on an `arg` type that can be efficiently moved.  Another thing to note is that `return std::make_shared<T>( std::move(arg) )` is often even better, unless `T` is extremely large in `sizeof` and you have long-lasting `weak_ptr`s to it.

Comment: @Yakk: If the underlying type `T` already has a move constructor, and the user passes the factory an rvalue ref, then the efficiency you are talking about is achieved already, with the perfect forwarding. If it only has lvalue ref constructors, then your factory will always make extra copies, and there is nothing the user can do about it. This makes your way not suitable for glue code, which this factory definitely is.

Answer (score 1):

> *)Why is number 3 is preferred than number 1 and number 2?

(1) won't work if `Arg` is non-copyable.
(2) won't allow you to pass an rvalue, as in `factory<int>(42);`

Note that none of the three examples involve perfect forwarding. I'm not sure what the subject of your question refers to.

> *)if factory(41) is called, why is called on rvalue?

I'm not sure I understand the question. `41` is an rvalue by definition.

> *)# define BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(type) type&&. what's && in this case?

`type&&` is an [rvalue reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) to `type`.